# Contraint reference constant not working

Tags: ios, swift

I've setup a reference to a constraint that i want to modify the constant value of. For some reason when i try to modify the constraint's constant value it doesn't work.

```
    var containerViewBottomAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    func setupToolBar() {
       ...
       containerViewBottomAnchor = containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
       containerViewBottomAnchor?.isActive = true


    }

    func modify(){
       containerViewBottomAnchor?.constant = -500
    }
```

But when i set the constant directly it works

```
containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -500).isActive = true
```

Comment: are you sure you call `setupToolBar`? otherwise the code seems correct - I guess it would not work only if `containerViewBottomAnchor` is nil - try using `containerViewBottomAnchor!.constant = -500` instead, if it crashes, then that's the case

Comment: any luck with it?

Comment: Thanks Milan, yes setupToolBar is called because when I change to the fixed constant without the reference it works. And I tried to force unwrap an nothing happened.

Comment: I’m still a noob, but is there anything else that could stop it from being modified

Comment: I've been doing things (animating, and stuff) like this all the time, and never stumbled upon this.. there must be something in the rest of the code that messes it up, can you show the whole code (I mean just for that class)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call layoutIfNeeded() after the constraint update:

```
func modify() {
    containerViewBottomAnchor?.constant = -500
    containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Otherwise the constraint is updated but the view doesn't change.